# Why does the constant in a wave's function temporal part is set to 1?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

Starting from the Schrödinger equation:
$$i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\psi(x,t)=\left(-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\hat{V}\right)\psi(x,t)$$
If we assume a solution of the form $\psi(x,t)=\phi(x)\xi(t)$ (separation of variables) we end up with (after dividing both sides by $\phi(x)\xi(t)$):
$$i\hbar \frac{\xi(t)'}{\xi(t)}=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x)}{\partial x^2}+\hat{V}(\mathbb{I})$$
where «$\mathbb{I}$» is what I assumed to be the identity function. So on one side we have something that depends on time, in the other we have something that depends only on position; the only way two functions that depend on different variables could possibly be the same is if they are both a constant:
$$i\hbar \frac{\xi(t)'}{\xi(t)}= C = -\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x)}{\partial x^2}+\hat{V}(\mathbb{I})$$
Solving the first member gives us:
$$ln|\xi(t)|=-i\frac{C}{\hbar}t+A \Leftrightarrow \xi(t)=Be^{-i\frac{C}{\hbar}t}\\ {(B=\pm e^{A}, \text{because of the absolute value; anyway B is a random constant})}$$
So why is the constant B set to 1? Is there any other reasonable explanation besides the *"if you put it on the Schrödinger equation it works"*?

Comment: Because we already include a constant in $\phi$, putting it also in $\xi$ is redundant.

Comment: Thank you very much.